# Ubuntu error message at boot

Tags: boot

For a few months I have had an error message showing up on my loading screen. I saw people describing similar messages here, but I couldn't get anything from the replies as I am not very experienced in fixing Ubuntu myself, so I thought I would try to post mine.

Here is a photo of the message:

[image: error message picture]

And here is the content of the above photo as text:

```
x86cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
ACPI Error: Needed Type [Reference], found [integer] 000000004c423534 (20210730/exresop-66)
ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20210730/dswexec-431)
ACPI Error:Aborting method /_PR.CPUO._PDC due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20210730/psparse-529)
ima:Error communicating to TMP chip
ima:Error communicating to TMP chip
ima:Error communicating to TMP chip
ima:Error communicating to TMP chip
ima:Error communicating to TMP chip
ima:Error communicating to TMP chip
ima:Error communicating to TMP chip
ima:Error communicating to TMP chip
dev/sda5: clean, 402263/14622720 files, 55561698/58476032 blocks
Bluetooth: hciO: unexpected event for Opcode 0xfc2f
```

This hasn't been a problem for months, but now my computer gets stuck on it and won't boot. It showed a message once about not recognising a USB device I had connected just before the issue arose yesterday, but that hasn't shown up again.

I'm thinking that it might be easier to try to recover the data I don't have backed up and reinstall Ubuntu, so if you have a tip about that please let me know as well.

Comment: Please also [edit] your question and add the version of Ubuntu you are using as a tag, as this could be relevant.